# Import images as planes -> flickering from a distance?

Tags: import, image

First of all i'd like to comment that i m relatively new to blender but know the basics.

My scenario: I import an image (as plane). Use a cube as an object. I use shrinkwrap modifier to stick the plane image to the cube. I use default values with an offset of 0.001 - 0.002

Everything is ok, but, when i go away from the object (zoom out scene), and also move it left right, i see some flickerings in my image.

Do i miss an option here?

Pic here

https://ibb.co/4tqQPtq

Comment: Try tweaking Blend Mode and Shadow Mode in Material Properties tab and see if it becomes better. Maybe Alpha Hashed instead of Opaque.
Also, in Shading try changing from Linear to Closest that image which you imported. If that doesn't work, try uploading .blend file, so someone will probably find solution.
Also, I didn't use shrinkwrap. I just placed my plane manualy as closest as I could.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)